# AS3 embedded tween only partially showing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When I `addChild` a movie clip with 60 frames embedded tween, only the last few frames are playing when running the SWF. Why?

```
function onClick10f2(e: MouseEvent) {    
    addChild(gdropBall1)
    gdropBall1.x = 356.10;
    gdropBall1.y = 28;
}
```

Comment: We'll need more to go by than this.   how do you create `gdropBall1`?

Comment: Likely you just need to stop `gdropBall1` until after you add it.

Comment: Problem was solved I just needed 'gdropBall1.gotoAndPlay(1);' to add at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved with `gdropBall1.gotoAndPlay(1);`

```
function onClick10f2(e: MouseEvent) {

   gdropBall1.gotoAndPlay(1);    
    addChild(gdropBall1)
    gdropBall1.x = 356.10;
    gdropBall1.y = 28;
```